# Printf give an undefined behavior while using Struct in C

Tags: arrays, c, struct, printf

I'm new to C Programming. Im really confused why printf gives undefined behavior output. I tried to double-check every command and I don't think there is a mistake with my current knowledge. What was wrong with my code?

```
struct Barang
    {
        int Kode;
        int Jumlah;
        int HargaSatuan;
        float Total;
        char Nama[20];
    }Brg[10];

    int i,j,harga=0,banyak;
    float rata=0;
    printf("Berapa banyak barang? : ");
    scanf("%d",&banyak);
    for (i=0;i<banyak;i++)
    {
        printf("\nBarang Ke-%d\n",i+1);
        printf("Masukkan Kode : ");
        scanf("%d",&Brg[i].Kode);
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Masukkan Nama Barang  : ");
        fgets(Brg[i].Nama,20,stdin);
        strtok(Brg[i].Nama, "\n" );
        printf("Masukkan Harga Satuan : ");
        scanf("%d",&Brg[i].HargaSatuan);
        printf("Ada Berapa Jumlah?    : ");
        scanf("%d",&Brg[i].Jumlah);
        harga+=Brg[i].HargaSatuan;
    }
    for (i=0;i<banyak;i++)
    {
        printf("\nBarang Ke-%d\n",i+1);
        printf("Kode         :  %d\n",Brg[i].Kode);
        printf("Nama Barang  : %s\n",Brg[i].Nama);
        printf("Harga Satuan : %d\n",Brg[i].HargaSatuan);
        printf("Jumlah       : %d\n",Brg[i].Jumlah);
    }
    j=i;
    Brg[i].Total=(float)(Brg[i].HargaSatuan*Brg[i].Jumlah);
    rata=(float)Brg[i].Total/j;
    printf("\nTotal Harga Semua Barang : %.2f\n",Brg[i].Total);
    printf("Rata-Rata Harga Barang     : %.2f\n",rata);
```

If I run it

```
Berapa banyak barang? : 2

Barang Ke-1
Masukkan Kode : 20
Masukkan Nama Barang  : Tes A
Masukkan Harga Satuan : 20
Ada Berapa Jumlah?    : 1

Barang Ke-2
Masukkan Kode : 10
Masukkan Nama Barang  : Tes B
Masukkan Harga Satuan : 30
Ada Berapa Jumlah?    : 2

Barang Ke-1
Kode         :  20
Nama Barang  : Tes A
Harga Satuan : 20
Jumlah       : 1

Barang Ke-2
Kode         :  10
Nama Barang  : Tes B
Harga Satuan : 30
Jumlah       : 2

Total Harga Semua Barang : 2093416448.00
Rata-Rata Harga Barang     : 1046708224.00

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 21.303 s
Press any key to continue.
```

It give me very wrong output and unexpected.
The right output should be like this:

```
Berapa banyak barang? : 2

Barang Ke-1
Masukkan Kode : 20
Masukkan Nama Barang  : Tes A
Masukkan Harga Satuan : 20
Ada Berapa Jumlah?    : 1

Barang Ke-2
Masukkan Kode : 10
Masukkan Nama Barang  : Tes B
Masukkan Harga Satuan : 30
Ada Berapa Jumlah?    : 2

Barang Ke-1
Kode         :  20
Nama Barang  : Tes A
Harga Satuan : 20
Jumlah       : 1

Barang Ke-2
Kode         :  10
Nama Barang  : Tes B
Harga Satuan : 30
Jumlah       : 2

Total Harga Semua Barang : 70
Rata-Rata Harga Barang     : 23.3

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 21.303 s
Press any key to continue.
```

How do I solve this? Thank you.

Comment: Passing an input-only stream (like `stdin`) to `fflush` is explicitly mentioned in the C specification as leading to *undefined behavior*. Any literature, tutorial or class that teaches it should be looked at with great suspicion.

Comment: `scanf("%d")` will produce undefined behavior if the input stream contains a value that cannot be represented in an int (eg INT_MAX + 1)

Answer (score 2):

When you do

```
Brg[i].Total=(float)(Brg[i].HargaSatuan*Brg[i].Jumlah);
rata=(float)Brg[i].Total/j;
```

you are outside the loop, which means that `i` will be an index out of range of your initialized data.

For your input with two entries in the array, the valid indexes will be `0` and `1`. The value of `i` after the loop will be `2`.

You need a separate `total` variable that you modify inside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in your loop:

```
for (i=0;i<banyak;i++)
{
    printf("\nBarang Ke-%d\n",i+1);
    printf("Kode         :  %d\n",Brg[i].Kode);
    printf("Nama Barang  : %s\n",Brg[i].Nama);
    printf("Harga Satuan : %d\n",Brg[i].HargaSatuan);
    printf("Jumlah       : %d\n",Brg[i].Jumlah);
}
j=i;
Brg[i].Total=(float)(Brg[i].HargaSatuan*Brg[i].Jumlah);
rata=(float)Brg[i].Total/j;
printf("\nTotal Harga Semua Barang : %.2f\n",Brg[i].Total);
```

When the loop is done, `i = banyak`, but values for `Brg[i]` are only defined for `i` up to `banyak - 1`. I think what you meant was:

```
float total = 0;
for (i = 0; i < banyak; i++) {
    printf("\nBarang Ke-%d\n",i+1);
    printf("Kode         : %d\n",Brg[i].Kode);
    printf("Nama Barang  : %s\n",Brg[i].Nama);
    printf("Harga Satuan : %d\n",Brg[i].HargaSatuan);
    printf("Jumlah       : %d\n",Brg[i].Jumlah);
    Brg[i].Total = (float)(Brg[i].HargaSatuan * Brg[i].Jumlah);
    total += Brg[i].total;
}
rata = total / banyak;
printf("\nTotal Harga Semua Barang : %.2f\n",total);
```

Comment: You still make the same mistake as the OP, and use `i` after the loop. And you don't accumulate the total, but only modify the `Total` of the current index. And you use the *uninitialized* value of the `Total` member.

Comment: You're right, @Some_programmer_dude... fixed now